# Migration from 2.2.4 enterprise to 2.3.5-p2 - setup:upgrade mysql error

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2.4, setup-upgrade, magento2.3.5

I am working on a 2.2.4 enterprise to 2.3.5-p2 migration.

I have gone through all steps such as composer, internal modules solutions, until setup:upgrade step. I searched for solution on the web, and tried to raise memory limits on MySQL server, but it doesn't work yet.

The upgrade ran smooth on a small development version of the database. But this is a huge client with +40k SKUs and some thousand monthly orders.

Anyone can help ?

Thanks !!!

> Updating modules: Schema creation/updates: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
> key constraint fails (`magento`.`#sql-1c_10`, CONSTRAINT
> `SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY
> (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE
> SET NULL), query was: ALTER TABLE `sales_order` MODIFY COLUMN
> `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMEN....

Comment: We are using Azure, Magento needs MySQL 5.7. It looks like the server runs 5.7 but this thing 'connector' responds as 5.6. I don't know if there might be the error.

Answer (score 0):

@Gustavo did you find a solution. I am also having the same issue when upgrading from Magento 2.3.2 to Magento 2.3.5-p1.